# Issues with importing libraries after installing xgboost

Tags: python, pandas, version, xgboost

I just installed xgboost (Python 3.5; Win 10) using:

```
conda install py-xgboost
```

I started a new notebook and a simple

```
 import pandas as pd
```

has given me this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c28917116b79> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import sklearn as sk
      3 from sklearn import metrics
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from scipy import stats

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 # numpy compat
---> 23 from pandas.compat.numpy import *
     24 
     25 try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 
      9 # numpy versioning
---> 10 _np_version = np.__version__
     11 _nlv = LooseVersion(_np_version)
     12 _np_version_under1p10 = _nlv < LooseVersion('1.10')

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'
```

A version error??

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like installation py-xgboost has downgraded numpy (there is a trace for it). Normally, I have not seen this as an issue with other installs. After I ran

```
conda update --all
```

numpy got updated with a newer version and seems like no more error like I had.

Very strange! Perhaps apps owners / admin should look into the install process